# Unable to load all the rows from text file into data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read all the text files from a directory and write it into a data frame. I am getting only the last row added in the data frame. other rows are overwritten in the same row. How do i append the rows.

Here is my code:

```
filepath=r"D:\Projects\textfiles"
chat_df = pd.DataFrame()
#os.chdir(filepath)
for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
     inputpath = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
     with open(inputpath, 'r') as file_data:
         lines=file_data.readlines()
         for line in lines:
             if line.startswith("["):
                    chat_meta_data = line.split(",",0)

                    chat_df['sender_name'] = chat_meta_data
                    
             else:
                    chat_content = line
                    chat_df['message_content'] = chat_content
display(chat_df)
```

Here is my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaAVz.png) data

Comment: Can you give more info about which type of files do you have in the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
import os
import pandas as pd

```
filepath = r"D:\Projects\textfiles"
chat_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sender_name', 'message_content'])  # Initialize DataFrame columns

for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    inputpath = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
    with open(inputpath, 'r') as file_data:
        lines = file_data.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("["):
                chat_meta_data = line.strip()  # Remove leading and trailing whitespace
            else:
                chat_content = line.strip()    # Remove leading and trailing whitespace
                chat_df = chat_df.append({'sender_name': chat_meta_data, 'message_content': chat_content}, ignore_index=True)

# Display the resulting DataFrame
display(chat_df)
```

The main difference is that instead of using the column assignment we used the append method of DataFrame:

```
chat_df = chat_df.append({'sender_name': chat_meta_data, 'message_content': chat_content}, ignore_index=True)
```

By this, we ensure that appends data to data frame and doesn't overwritten it

Comment: Look over the pandas.read_csv or read_excel methods it reads the file in a more optimal way